# In what business scenarios do we create a non referenced RMA in Oracle order management

Tags: oracle-apps, oracle-ebs

-> Generally we create a Return Material Authorization (RMA) against 
     a Sales Order (SO) when customer rejects the goods.
-> In the above case, if we create a Return Order then the Sales Order 
     will be referenced here.
-> But Oracle ERP Cost Management module provides us to create a 
     Return order without referring the sales order also.
-> So generally in what business scenarios do we create that?

Answer (score 0):

When a company sells it's products to distributors, there is an understanding between the Company (seller) and distributor that the distributor would return 5-10% of a product to the seller if it is unsold.

The above said scenario is called Stock Rotation RMA which doesn't have reference Sales Order reference.

For further details on RMA, please read the below link.
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A60725_05/html/comnls/us/oe/esayrmas.htm

Answer (score 0):

We applied the same that you asked about when we were in going live period, we did all RMA without referencing them to SO because we didn't have a reference SO.

Regards.
Omar Al-Okaidi

Comment: Yeah, but what about the original Sales order? How you people nullified Debit memo against credit memo? Have you imported any SO's from the outsourced systems?

Comment: We uploaded the open balances of the customers on the going live then if there is RMA exist we will apply it to the customer open balance, also, we let the return reference on the sales order line "Null"